# Symfony try project in prod environment leads me to an error

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I was trying to run my project for the first time in a production environment I did not go how I expected.

After following the instructions from here
https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html I got an error in my `localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php` page :

```
ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "SensioGeneratorBundle" from namespace     "Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle" in D:\logiciel\wamp\www\Symfony\app\AppKernel.php line 28. Do you need     to "use" it from another namespace?
```

Is it possible that composer made a mistake or something? I really don't know how to solve this

Comment: Hi @Vincent, you should try ```composer update```.

Comment: Hello :) i just tried to set again php composer.phar install -dev --optimize-autoloader then i did composer udate and it's working well ;) thanks !

Comment: @Vincent : `php composer.phar install -dev --optimize-autoloader` Are you sure you need the `dev` packages in `prod` environment? I suggest you to use the [`--prefer-dist` option](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install), it speeds up the installation.

Answer (score 34):

I had the same problem and solved it by doing:

```
export SYMFONY_ENV=prod
```

Comment: Yes! Just if it helps to others: What it is `dev` for composer is one thing, and what it is `dev` for symfony is another. Running `composer install --no-dev` without saying `--no-scripts` still runs the scripts, but they are not run with the `-env=prod` unless you export this variable. The `GeneratorBundle` is both in the `dev` of the composer and the `dev` of the `AppKernel`. If you don't set the `SYMFONY_ENV` variable to prod, your scripts will try to load the `dev` part of the `AppKernel` which instances a bundle that was never downloaded by the `composer`. Thanks for the tip!!

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, running `composer update` really solve the problem.

Comment: No, it's not a solution. It will break dependencies' versions defined in composer.lock by updating it and updating the dependencies. Thus, there will be a difference with your dev environment. In production, use `composer install`.

Comment: Please share more details. What makes you think that this solves the problem? Keep in mind that an explanation helps others to learn from your answer

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit out of scope, but I would like to add to [Pogus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39305681/2693875) that **if you are using Ansible for running composer**, you have to provide this env variable like this:

```
- name: "Install your app dependencies"
  composer:
    command: install
    no_dev: yes
    optimize_autoloader: yes
    working_dir: "/your/app/dir"
  environment:                      # <---- here
    SYMFONY_ENV: prod               # <---/
```

...or in a similar way, read the [Ansible environment variables docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html) for details.

Setting it places like `/etc/profile.d/set-symfony-env-to-prod.sh` scripts will be used by programs running on your server, but NOT by Ansible.